# What versions of Java do Anypoint Studio and the Mule Runtime support?

Tags: java, mule, java-9, anypoint-studio, java-10

I am trying to migrate from Java 8 to Java 10 and determine which versions of Java Anypoint Studio and the Mule Runtimes support.

Is it possible to set them up to run with Java 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a list of the details below. In short, at the time of this writing, Java 9 and 10 are not currently supported by any version of Anypoint Studio or the Mule runtime.

- Anypoint 6 here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-studio/v/6/faq-jdk-requirement

  - All runtimes support Java 7 and 8, except 3.5.x, which only supports 7, and 3.9.x, which only supports 8.
- Anypoint 6.5 here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-studio/v/6.5/faq-jdk-requirement

  - All runtimes support Java 7 and 8, except 3.5.x, which only supports 7, and 3.9.x, which only supports 8.
- Anypoint 7.x here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-studio/v/7.2/faq-jdk-requirement

  - Only supports Java 8.

Comment: I have gone through the documentation on mulesoft and anypoint studio even before i posted my question. What we are trying is might be we can upgrade to JDK 9/10 with older versions. I tried passing vm args  in mule studio 7.2 but it doesn't start up and gave error that it support JDK 8. Change configuration before start up.